# How to call a completion method everytime ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method is returned

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I am using

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => MyMethod(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5));
```

I want to call the following method from the main thread every time the call to MyMethod is completed:

```
UpdateGui()
{

}
```

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Call `Control.Invoke` from within `MyMethod` to marshal the execution of a delegate onto the UI thread.

Comment: Why not use `Task` and continuations for that?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: Yes, even better!

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, There is deadlock issues with the UpdateGui that I dont understand, so I want to run it on the main thread.  using ContinueWith fires a new task and the deadlock issues will remain. all I want is to call a method on the main thread after the spun thread method returns.

Comment: @user277498: You can specify the synchronization context you want to use when launching tasks/continuations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a global counter of work items queued and an object to protect it:

```
int runningTasks = 0;
object locker = new object();
```

Every time a task is added increment the counter:

```
lock(locker) runningTasks++;
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => MyMethod(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5));
```

At the end of `MyMethod` decrement the counter and signal the main thread:

```
lock(locker) 
{
    runningTasks--;
    Monitor.Pulse(locker);
}
```

In the main thread (assuming this is not the GUI thread!):

```
lock(locker)
{
    while(runningTasks > 0)
    {
        Monitor.Wait(locker);            
        UpdateGUI();
    }
}
```

This way you also have a barrier to wait for all pending tasks to finish.

In case you don't want to wait, just skip the main thread completely and call `UpdateGUI` to forward updates to the GUI thread when `MyMethod` finishes.

**Note** that inside `MyMethod` you should have some form of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` (WPF) or `Control.BeginInvoke` (WinForms) otherwise you cannot update the GUI safely!

Comment: I don't understand. *locker* is a System.Object, right? Are .Pulse and .Wait extension methods for System.Object? And the lock around the while loop, won't that block the lock and decrement at the end of MyMethod forever?

Comment: @KristoferA-Huagati.com: No, when you call `Monitor.Wait(locker)` inside a `lock(locker)` the lock is automatically released to allow other threads to acquire the lock. Also, `Pulse` and `Wait` are static methods of class `Monitor`, not extensions of `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Post a call to the updategui method back to the sync context for the ui thread at the end of the threadpool method...

Example:

```
private SynchronizationContext _syncContext = null;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //get hold of the sync context
    _syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //queue a call to MyMethod on a threadpool thread
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => MyMethod());
}

private void MyMethod()
{
    //do work...

    //before exiting, call UpdateGui on the gui thread
    _syncContext.Post(
        new SendOrPostCallback(
            delegate(object state)
            {
                UpdateGui();
            }), null);
}

private void UpdateGui()
{
    MessageBox.Show("hello from the GUI thread");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `MyMethod` is a synchronous method, invoked inside `QueueUserWorkItem` in order to make it execute asynchronously, the following approach may be used:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => 
{
    MyMethod(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5);
    UpdateGui();
});
```

**Note** that you have to update GUI elements inside `UpdateGui()` by calling `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 0):

This may keep the client cleaner letting the class handle the cross threading switching mechanism. This way the GUI consumes your class in normal fashion.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ExampleController.MyController controller;
    public Form1()
    {          
        InitializeComponent();
        controller = new ExampleController.MyController((ISynchronizeInvoke) this);
        controller.Finished += controller_Finished;

    }
    void controller_Finished(string returnValue)
    {
        label1.Text = returnValue;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        controller.SubmitTask("Do It");
    }
}
```

The GUI form subscribes to events of the class unaware they are mulch-threaded.

```
public class MyController
{
    private ISynchronizeInvoke _syn;
    public MyController(ISynchronizeInvoke syn) {  _syn = syn; }
    public event FinishedTasksHandler Finished;
    public void SubmitTask(string someValue)
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => submitTask(someValue));
    }

    private void submitTask(string someValue)
    {
        someValue = someValue + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
//Finished(someValue); This causes cross threading error if called like this.

        if (Finished != null)
        {
            if (_syn.InvokeRequired)
            {
                _syn.Invoke(Finished, new object[] { someValue });
            }
            else
            {
                Finished(someValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```