# C# execute Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem callback in main thread affinity

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I want to load a bunch of images from disk in Unity. So I want to use thread pool do actually load the image bytes in a helper thread and then apply the texture in the main thread.

I made a function that gets a path as an input and loads the image bytes with the help of `System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and when it finishes it calls a callback that creates a texture out of those bytes and applies it to the game object.

The problem I'm having is that the callback is executed with the affinity of the worker thread. And unity doesn't allow non-main threads to make modifications to it's data.

Is there a way to execute the callback in the main thread's affinity?

This is the relevant code:

```cs
 public delegate void OnBytesLoaded(byte[] bytes);

    private void LoadBytesToTexture(byte[] bytes)
    {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(100, 100);
        texture.LoadImage(bytes);
        thumbnail.texture = texture;
    }

    private void LoadTextureImage(string imagePath)
    {
        OnBytesLoaded callback = new OnBytesLoaded(LoadBytesToTexture);

        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
            Debug.Log($"Loaded image bytes");
            callback?.Invoke(bytes);
        });
    }
```

As I said, my problem is that `LoadBytesToTexture` is executing in the affinity of the thread pool thread, and not the main thread.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930007/how-to-call-a-completion-method-everytime-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-method-is help?

Comment: @mjwills Someone there says:" Call `Control.Invoke` from within MyMethod to marshal the execution of a delegate onto the UI thread". This is exactly what I'm doing. Though the delegate is still isn't executed on the main thread.

Comment: @mjwills `callback?.Invoke(bytes);`

Comment: The `Invoke` in `callback?.Invoke(bytes);` is [a compiler-generated method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7907079/11178549). It is not the same with [`Control.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke).

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias I see. Though it seems `Control.Invoke` isn't relevant to me because it's part of widnows forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is concept in **.NET** called [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8).

In brief the **sync context** can **delegate work** to the thread it has affinity to (depending on the framework this can be the **thread pool**, **GUI thread**, the thread that **created the sync context** ... etc).

Using something like this should do the job:

```
private void LoadTextureImage(string imagePath)
{
    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    OnBytesLoaded callback = new OnBytesLoaded(bytes => syncContext .Post(_ => LoadBytesToTexture(bytes), null));

    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
        Debug.Log($"Loaded image bytes");
        callback?.Invoke(bytes);
    });
}
```

---

**NOTE:**
`SynchronizationContext` depends on the calling context.

In the current scenario `syncContext` in captured in closure of `bytes => syncContext.Post`, this way
the .`Current` property will return `syncContext` delegating work back to the **GUI thread** (because `LoadTextureImage` is called from the **GUI thread**),
otherwise if we have used `bytes => SynchronizationContext.Current.Post` this could yield **null** or `syncContext` that will delegate work back to the **ThreadPool** (because .`Current` is called from thread on the pool).

---

**Requested additional info from the comments about:**

```
OnBytesLoaded(bytes => syncContext .Post(_ => LoadBytesToTexture(bytes), null))
```

This
`OnBytesLoaded callback = new OnBytesLoaded(LoadBytesToTexture);`
is the same as
`OnBytesLoaded callback = new OnBytesLoaded(bytes => LoadBytesToTexture(bytes));`

In the original version of the code you have used `LoadBytesToTexture` as delegate for `OnBytesLoaded` (which expects method / delegate with the following definition **byte[] -> void**), now we are passing new delegate that will use the `syncContext` to queue `LoadBytesToTexture` back to the GUI thread which again has the same definition **bytes[] -> void.**
Instead of calling  directly `LoadBytesToTexture`, we are telling the `syncContext` to queue `LoadBytesToTexture` back to the **GUI thread** with using the bytes passed in this call `callback?.Invoke(bytes)`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! 
Though I'm a bit confused about the syntax of this line:
`new OnBytesLoaded(bytes => syncContext .Post(_ => LoadBytesToTexture(bytes), null))`

Comment: It did. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution is the only way I've found so far that doesn't require a `MonoBehaviour`.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create  simple dispatcher script and attach it to an empty active gameobject in your scene.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// Helps dispatch task results to the main thread to be able to operate on unity's API like SetActive, enabled etc...
/// </summary>
public class MainThreadDispatcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    Queue<Action> jobs = new Queue<Action>();
    static MainThreadDispatcher Instance = null;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        while (jobs.Count > 0)
        {
            var next = jobs.Dequeue();
            if(next != null)
            {
                next.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Dispatches a function to be executed on unity's main thread to be able to use unity's API.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newJob"></param>
    public static void Dispatch(Action newJob)
    {
        if (newJob == null)
            return;
        Instance.jobs.Enqueue(newJob);
    }
}
```

2) Edit your `LoadBytesToTexture` method body to be:

```
private void LoadBytesToTexture(byte[] bytes)
{
    MainThreadDispatcher.Dispatch(()=>
    {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(100, 100);
        texture.LoadImage(bytes);
        thumbnail.texture = texture;
    });
}
```

So basically to execute anything on the main thread do `MainThreadDispatcher.Dispatch(()=> code);`

Comment: Is there any advantage to using this over what @vasil oreshenski suggested by using the SynchronizationContext?

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 I am not familiar enough with Unity3d but MonoBehaviour is specific for Unity - which probably is the better option, and the SyncContext solution is more general. MonoBehaviour is probably using the SyncContext at some point, so MonoBehaviour is more like a wrapper (more suitable for Unity i guess).